# ActionCable rails 7 unable to intercept message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

This is in my #index of my videos controller

```
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("To_User", { body: "This Room is Best Room." })
```

This is from where message gets streamed.

```
class ApiUpdateChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "To_User"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

This is my update_api_channel.js

```
consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: "ApiUpdateChannel", room: "To_User"}, {
  connected() {
    console.log('blabla')
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log('klakla');
  }
});
```

I am able to see 'blabla' in my console. But there is no 'klakla'. I am stuck with this for a day now.

Comment: you have to `connect` before you can `broadcast`. if you're navigating to index page then broadcasting then rendering a page then connecting it's too late to receive. you might want to open two tabs and keep one open to see if you receive anything.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your JS assets? Something like `rails assets:clobber` and `yarn build`. May be your `received` code was added but not used in the compiled file

Comment: @Alex that worked out. The problem is I need to update the current_tab. Like, when a user clicks on Make_Request, I can broadcast messages to the user about the status of the api call.  Is that achievable?

Comment: Also, wanted to ask if it is possible to process __Actioncable.server.broadcast__ from sidekiq. Mine is working from controller but not from sidekiq

Comment: sure, once the page is loaded you're connected. you just can't refresh the page after the click, which should not even be an issue with Turbo. hard to say what's wrong on your current tab without some details. sidekiq - runs in a separate process/server, you need to switch to redis adapter (in cable.yml) so actioncable could have a way to communicate from anywhere.